# for issuing in cbt CLI 'cbt deleterow <rowkey>', how can i escape space character in a rowkey?

Tags: character, space, delete-row, row-key, cbt

Please if anyone knows how to get succeeded on that :

I have to get rid of a set of rows in a bigtable. Their rowkey contains SPACE characters.
i am trying to escape those space characters but I´m still getting No-go (i.e. error msg 'bad argument ')

all advices are welcome.
thanks in advance

Masa

issue CLI command 'cbt deleterow ' which rowkeys contain space characters.
i´d like to find out a way to escape these space characters to set the correct rowkey to deleterow be successful.

Answer (score 0):

after some more readings and tests, I could find the way out.

blablabla_1@devops:~$ cbt -project blablabla -instance blablabla lookup br-blablablatable $'AA DU ROYAUME20240301#0000000A000001B#' columns=CF1:id_produit 2024/03/18 12:22:51 -creds flag unset, will use gcloud credential

---

AA DU ROYAUME20240301#0000000A000001B#

....

from

https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/cbt-reference :

cbt lookup   [columns=:,...] [cells-per-column=] [app-profile=]

row-key                             String or raw bytes. ***Raw bytes must be enclosed in single quotes and have a dollar-sign prefix***

so i grasped that space is considered raw byte if it is present in a rowkey